# Splitting Comma Separated string in TSQL and converting result into rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split

Can some one help me in this case? I have this table input

| ID | BuildingName | Rooms | Details | Contact |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BurjKhalifa | 2,4-9,12 | RoomsAvailable | +971-12-0000 |

and I want this output

| ID | BuildingName | Rooms | Details | Contact |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BurjKhalifa | 2 | RoomsAvailable | +971-12-0000 |
| 1 | BurjKhalifa | 4 | RoomsAvailable | +971-12-0000 |
| 1 | BurjKhalifa | 5 | RoomsAvailable | +971-12-0000 |
| 1 | BurjKhalifa | 6 | RoomsAvailable | +971-12-0000 |
| 1 | BurjKhalifa | 7 | RoomsAvailable | +971-12-0000 |
| 1 | BurjKhalifa | 8 | RoomsAvailable | +971-12-0000 |
| 1 | BurjKhalifa | 9 | RoomsAvailable | +971-12-0000 |
| 1 | BurjKhalifa | 12 | RoomsAvailable | +971-12-0000 |

Comment: Column names or should we just guess?

Comment: ID | Buildingname | Rooms | Details | Contact 

Sir, These are my colums

Comment: Blargh, T-SQL is not going to be your friend here. Especially if you could have something like `'1-3, 5, 7, 9-22, 24, 27, 29-30, 33 & 35'`

Answer (score 4):

With the aid of a CROSS APPLY (or two)  and an ad-hoc tally/numbers table

**Example**

```
Select A.ID
      ,A.BuildingName
      ,Rooms = C.N
      ,A.Details
      ,A.Contact
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( 
                Select R1=min(try_convert(int,B2.value))
                      ,R2=max(try_convert(int,B2.value))
                 From  string_split(Rooms,',') B1
                 Cross Apply string_split(Value,'-') B2
                 Group By B1.value
             )B
 Join ( Select Top 500 N=-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2 ) C
   on N between R1 and R2
 Order by ID,C.N
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!

Comment: Yeah it's good but can you make it work by using loop?